# How to dynamically change connection string with each API Call

Tags: asp.net-web-api, entity-framework-6, connection-string

I'm new to working with APIs, but from what I understand I have created a service folder with 2 classes called DataRepository and IDataRepository. The DataRepository class interacts with the DataContext class. However my Connection string is not in the DataContext class, but in the Startup class. The reason that I'd like to be able to dynamically change the connection string is because, I have many instances of the same database. Each one represent the data of a different. Now the issue is how can I set the connection string dynamically through each webapi call? I plan on getting the connection string parameter with each call.

Comment: Getting connection string from API call is a bad practice. Instead you can use dependency injection to resolve you datacontext with connection string that each controller requires.

Answer (score 0):

are you using authorization tokens? if so, you can put your connection string as part of the claims. i suggest to not put the whole connection string in the parameter. if you want an easier approach, you can have a string parameter that can tell if what type of db it should go to, 
ex.

```
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> youApi(string type){
   //then you can have a switch statement to know what database it will go to
  string connectionString= "";    
  switch(type)
  case "database1": 
      connectionString = "datasrc=database1"; 
   //and so on
}
```

im not sure if this is the best approach. i hope this helps.